# Is there a way to pass multiple functions to an AngularJS directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am building a dropdown menu directive which allows you to optionally attach a function to each item in the list. I know how to pass one function per attribute into the directive, but I'm hoping that there is a way to pass multiple functions.

```
<dropdown items="['item1', 'item2']" actions="['action1()', 'action2()']"></dropdown>
```

or better yet:

```
<dropdown items="[{'item1':action1()}, {'item2':action2()}]"></dropdown>
```

which could be used to generate:

```
<dropdown items="['item1', 'item2']" actions="['action1()', 'action2()']">
    <a ng-click="action1()">item1</a>
    <a ng-click="action2()">item2</a>
</dropdown>
```

Comment: Why not `action1="action1()" action2="action2()`. You probably won't have too much functions and map them with the `&` on the directive. Otherwise, passing the array (with `=`) will force you to iterate over the array in order to parse the functions.

Comment: It seems cleaner to pass one object in. How would I access the functions through `=`? It just ends up treating the whole thing as a string and I can't access the actual functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `=` object notation for your scope in accepting an **array of objects with properties** that you can assign to your directive.

**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/ibB6i5EFUgpZkS54SnfA?p=preview)**

*Controller*

```
  .controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

    var action = function() {
      window.alert(this.label);
    };

    $scope.items = [{
      label: 'Item 1',
      action: action
    }, {
      label: 'Item 2',
      action: action
    }, {
      label: 'Item 3',
      action: action
    }, {
      label: 'Item 4',
      action: action
    }];
  })
```

*Directive*

```
  .directive('dropdown', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        items: '='
      },
      template: 
        '<div ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-click="item.action()">' + 
          '<a ng-bind="item.label"></a>' +
        '</div>'
    };
  });
```

*index.html*

```
  <body ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <dropdown items="items"></dropdown>
  </body>
```

Comment: what if action takes arguments?

Comment: Check this [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/GHFk4nm342XU2Q4sD1lC?p=preview) :)

Comment: thanks but I mean in action property:

$scope.items = [{
      label: 'Item 1',
      action: action(arg)
    },

Comment: What is your use case? if this is going to be another problem that is perhaps entirely different from the use case represented by this problem, then I suggest you ask another question :)

Comment: I just want to pass parameters to action function:

var action = function(parameter) {
      alert(parameter);
    };

Answer (score 0):

to pass any form of function to a directive that does same thing in thesense ike a call back from the directive to execute the function , the method should be as below

1. First of all use the return scope to contain the functionName : '&' as it is used in passing functions
2. Then returning it back should look like this from ur template ng-click='functionName({params:values[,params2:value2]})'

as the above would send the param as argument to the calling controller calling the directive

```js
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  
  $scope.items=['value1','value2','value3'];
  $scope.items2=['value12','value22','value32'];
  
  $scope.clicked='';
  
  $scope.alert=function(val){
    $scope.clicked=val;
  }
  
   $scope.alerti=function(val){
  $scope.clicked=val+"-Second";
  }
  
});

app.directive('direct', function(){
  return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope : {
          actionTest:'&',
          tests:'='
        },
       // controller: 'ctrl',
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="test in tests" ng-click="actionTest({val:test})">{{test}} </li></ul>'
  }
});
/*
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope){
  
});*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
<div  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>CLicked : {{clicked}}</p>
    
    <direct tests='items' action-test='alert(val)'></direct>
  
    <!--with a different action function-->
     <direct tests='items2' action-test='alerti(val)'></direct>
 
  </div>
</div>
```